# Extract variable and coefficient from equation elegantly

Tags: symbolic, coefficients

I have quadratic equation like $eq = x2-7*x5^2$ and vector $xx=\{x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,...\}$. I need to do some nice calculations which will give me coefficient $k=7$, $y=x2$ and $x=x5$, so that equation $y=k*x^2$ is the same as my original equation. Eq is a good equation, so finding $k$, $y$ and $x$ is possbile. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but let it be for a start.

```
eq = x2-7 x5^5
```

One can extract the list of variables by

```
xx = Variables[eq]
```

> {x2, x5}

Then, find the list of exponents and coefficients:

```
rules = CoefficientRules[eq, xx]
```

> {{1, 0} -> 1, {0, 2} -> -7}

The output means that the first coordinate, `x2`, has power `1` (that comes from the `{1,0}` part) and a coefficient `1`; the second coordinate, `x5`, has power `2` and coefficient `-7`. (You can add a term like `x2 x5` to see how it works.)

That gives a list of rules that one can use to reproduce the initial polynomial `eq` with arbitrary variables:

```
eqNew = FromCoefficientRules[rules, {y, x}]
```

> -7 x^2 + y

I understand that your `eq==0`, so

```
Simplify[eqNew == 0]
```

> 7 x^2 == y

Or

```
y = y /. First@Solve[eqNew == 0, y]
```

> 7 x^2

assigns `7 x^2` to `y`:

```
y
```

> 7 x^2

but I don't know how general you want it to be and what purposes should it serve.

Comment: Just a note that `Variables` will only return the right variables under certain assumptions (like the expression being a  polynomial). If you have more complicated expressions then you'd need to do something along the lines of `Cases[N[expr], _Symbol, Infinity]` to retrieve the variables

Comment: @gpap That's not ultimately general; consider `Cases[Exp[Sin[\[Pi] x]], _Symbol, Infinity]`. One should somehow use also `Except[E,Pi]`.

Comment: That's why I used `N`, otherwise all these are read off as symbols. It's still not failsafe but at least picks out "more" variables

Comment: Yes, it works with `N`. In case one wants to avoid it, maybe use `Cases` twice: `Cases[Cases[Exp[Sin[Pi x]], _Symbol, Infinity], Except[E | Pi]]`, or with `DeleteCases`.